# Moving windows XP embedded to new hardware

Tags: hard-drive, window, hardware-detection, windows-xp-embedded

I'm trying to move windows XP embedded to new computer since the current computer failed.

I've cloned the disc with "Acronis true image" and used "fixide" to reset the controlled driver.

And I get restarts in loop.

From what I understand till now, windows XPE is hardware specific.

What is did not understand is:

1. Can it work on new but similar (same model) hardware?
2. Is it possible to make windows xpe installation work on entirely different hardware?

Answer (score 0):

If your previous (original) hardware configure is OK, you can run

```
C:\Windows\system32\SysPrep\sysprep.exe /generalize
```

This will allow hardware config change.

However as you've said your original computer is down, I don't think there's any other possibilites.

Comment: What about getting new copmuter with the exact same specs? wont work either?

Comment: I personally succeeded with **exactly same** hard config with other versions of Windows (XP/7/10/) but not XP Emb. You can test it yourself. You may need to set BIOS to be exactly same, too.

Comment: I got the old computer to work, and there is no 'sysprep.exe' not even folder, do you know if it's different for windows xpe?

Comment: Sorry but I'm unsure if SysPrep is available for XPe. Maybe you should search on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=xp+embedded+sysprep)?

Comment: it's not, They use fbreseal.exe to create distributed image, and it seems that it's not possible to do it twice

Comment: FBReseal cannot replace SysPrep because SysPrep not only clears SIDs but also removes device-specific settings (and ket the system re-generate them again at next boot).

Answer (score 0):

If you can hook up the old and new harddrives to a pc, or boot the old pc into a linux session and connect the new harddrive you could use straight dd, or cat to do a bitwise copy of the old windows onto the new drive. I have moved windows partitions this way successfully, you just have to make sure it is the exact same hardware on the new pc or it will require a new license upon boot.

You could also boot into linux on the old pc, hook up a usb, and then dd windows onto the usb, boot into linux on the new pc with the usb stick with windows inserted, then dd it again onto the new hard drive

`cat /dev/sdX /dev/sdY
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=1024`